# mysql combining two columns

Tags: mysql

I need a little help in mysql. I have a table(say `tablea`) like this

```
tablea
--------------------------------------------
col1                         col2
a                            1
b                            1
c                            1
h                            3
d                            2
e                            2
f                            2
--------------------------------------------
```

After combining, my output should be

```
col3
--------
1
a
b
c
3
h
2
d
e
f
--------
```

Any idea on how to get this output?

Comment: You are assuming there is an intrinsic ordering of rows in a MySQL table - unless you have an ID field or something to order by, you can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UNION` operator, like so:

```
SELECT col1 AS col3
FROM tablea

UNION ALL

SELECT col2 AS col3
FROM tablea
```

Comment: well, thanks Steve, for the fast response.:) but, i need the output to be in the order as shown in the example. I dont think it will be like that when we use union all

Comment: that will retun `a
b
c
h
d
e
f
1
1
1
3
2
2
2` and OP is different

Comment: Thank you diEcho - I would like a description of the ordering criteria, rather than just repeating the example.

Comment: I need in this order as told above. 1 a b c 3 h 2 d e f. First col2, then corresponding col1 values. This is need to be done in loop. But, not sure how .

Comment: But what defines the order of values in the master table?  There is no intrinsic order to rows in a database table.